# Can't uninstall heroku gem on Fedora

Tags: ruby, fedora

When I try to uninstall I get:

```
> sudo gem uninstall heroku
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::InstallError)
    heroku is not installed in GEM_HOME, try:
    gem uninstall -i /usr/share/gems heroku
```

OK, I'll try that:

```
> sudo gem uninstall -i /usr/share/gems heroku
Remove executables:
    heroku

in addition to the gem? [Yn]  Y
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /usr/share/gems/bin directory.
```

I'm at a loss here. What do I need to do to remove this?

Comment: are you using rbenv or rvm ? also can you see who  owns the directory where the gems are installed . you know you can just cd into that directory and just rm -rf  .

Comment: I'm not sure what rbenv or rvm are, I just started using ruby. The directories seem to belong to root.